# Jquery filtering content (show / hide ) using radio buttons

Tags: jquery

Hey I am looking for a very simply jQuery code that displays a div when a certain radio button is selected, and hides that div if that radio button is "deselected" based on radio button value.

I figured it out how to make it work with radio buttons for one filter, but I want to work it out for two filters say

1. based on which **type** it belongs
2. based on no of ........**quantity**

**Here is the code which works for first filter (type):**

```
<script>
    var $filters = $("input:radio[name='type']"); 


var $categoryContent = $('#mainhide .mainresultbox');
var $errorMessage = $('#errorMessage');
$filters.click(function() {
    // if any of the radio buttons for brand are checked, you want to show div's containing their value, and you want to hide all the rest.
    $categoryContent.hide();
     var $selectedFilters = $filters.filter(':checked');
    if ($selectedFilters.length > 0) {
        $errorMessage.hide();
        $selectedFilters.each(function (i, el) {
            $categoryContent.filter(':contains(' + el.value + ')').show();
        });
    } else {
        $errorMessage.show();
    }

});
</script>
```

**Here is the HTML for radio buttons.**

```
<ul>
    <li><label for="cdg"><input type="radio" id="cdg" name="type" value="brand1"> brand1</label></li>
    <li><label for="cdh"><input type="radio" id="cdh" name="type" value="brand2"> brand1</label></li>
    <li><label for="cdi"><input type="radio" id="cdi" name="type" value="brand3"> brand1</label></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><label for="cdj"><input type="radio" id="cdj" name="quantity" value="10">10</label></li>
    <li><label for="cdk"><input type="radio" id="cdk" name="quantity" value="20">20</label></li>
    <li><label for="cdl"><input type="radio" id="cdl" name="quantity" value="30">30</label></li>
</ul>
```

**Here is the div and their content**

```
<div id="#mainhide">
  <div>brand1 in stock - 10</div>
  <div>brand1 in stock - 20</div>
  <div>brand1 in stock - 30</div>
</div>
<div id="errorMessage">reset all fliters</div>
```

How can i make both filters work, can any one help me....

Thank you,
Naresh Kamireddy

Comment: your code is weird.you have used checkbox with name fli as filter but there are no such checkbox elements in html code you have mentioned.

Comment: I have edited question can you check it now @ Milind Anantwar

Comment: :what are the activities you want to do based on two filters that you have mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You can not use special character in id, id should follow valid rules.
you have used `<div id="#mainhide">.` this is invalid id name

use : `<div id="mainhide">`

```
ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
```

More info :

[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want but you can have a look at this:

Also its `<div id="mainhide">` not `<div id="#mainhide">`

http://jsfiddle.net/yyCSQ/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can refilter like you did with an attribute selector :

```
var $selectedFilters = $filters.filter(':checked').filter('[value="10"]';
```

I would also use `$(document).ready(function(){[your code here]});` instead of wildly loading JS while the page is still loading.
And I also suggest not using `#` in your IDs as suggested by others.

[JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)